# Inserting watermark into Telerik Radrichtextbox

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, telerik, watermark

I am using Telerik Richtexbox version- 2012.2.607.1040 for Silverlight . I am displaying  word documents in the text box using DocxFormatProvider . I wanted to know if it is possible to add watermark to every page displayed in the textbox **programatically** so that I dont have to insert watermark in each individual document from MS word . The richtext box doesn't support [watermark natively](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/richtextbox/watermark-for-radrichtextbox.aspx) and the only way is by adding a custom layer according to the telerik support .

Comment: Can you show us how you have added the watermark so far, and what if anything you have tried to set it from code. There are a few ways to go about this, and the most appropriate for you depends on how you are using it.

Comment: @TriggerPin In added the watermark by following the steps mentioned on this page [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/word-help/create-a-watermark-from-a-picture-HA101884436.aspx#_Toc263170648) . I am storing the documents in a database and then the telerik Richtextbox displays it as it is in the document .

Answer (score 0):

With the present-day versions of Telerik UI for Silverlight controls, this feature is natively supported by RadRichTextBox:

```
WatermarkTextSettings textSettings = new WatermarkTextSettings();
textSettings.Text = "Purple Watermark";
textSettings.RotateAngle = 30;
textSettings.Opacity = 1;
textSettings.ForegroundColor = Colors.Purple;

this.radRichTextBox.SetWatermarkText(textSettings);
```

There is detailed [help article](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radrichtextbox/features/watermark.html#manipulating-watermarks-programmatically) in the Telerik's UI for Silverlight documentation.